# Facebook user_id as MongoDB BSON ObjectId?

Tags: facebook, indexing, mongodb, bson

I'm rebuilding [Lovers on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/loversapp) with Sinatra & Redis. I like Redis because it doesn't have the long (12-byte) [BSON ObjectIds](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-TheBSONObjectIdDatatype) and I am storing sets of Facebook user_ids for each user. The sets are requests_sent, requests_received, & relationships, and they all contain Facebook user ids.

I'm thinking of switching to MongoDB because I want to use it's geospatial indexing. If I do, I'd want to use the FB user ids as the _id field because I want the sets to be small and I want the JSON responses to be small. But, is the BSON ObjectId better (more efficient for MongoDB) to use than just an integer (fb user_id)?

Comment: tried asking on mongo forums as well?.

Comment: I am in a similar situation. I have a very large number of tiny documents with multiple indexes and heavy insert/upsert load. I am currently trying to reduce the size of the indexes to improve performance, and (before I do the experiments), am wondering if I am going down the right path...

Answer (score 2):

There are no major efficiency differences as far as I know ***except*** in certain cases like ordering by date (since the ObjectId's have the datetime in them, etc.)

For example you'd lose the ability to simply order by the **_id** you'd also lose the benefits for [sharding and distribution](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-SequenceNumbers). Aside from that, *while I'd still personally use the ObjectId's anyhow* ... as long as the **int** is unquie (of course) ... you should be just fine.

Since the **_id** always "comes back" in a query I suppose you'd save a little time and data transfer (a bitty bit.)

You can even make your **_id** an array if you wanted, and it'll all index nicely see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591397/effect-mongodb-id-generation-on-indexing/4591619#4591619) (not that I'd necessarily recommend that most of the time.)

Also see: [Optimizing Object IDs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs)