# use MongoDb in place of MYSQl,SQL

Tags: facebook, json, mongodb

We want to store the Facebook o/p which is in JSON format in mongoDb. We were parsing the json object and storing the content of json as columns in mysql. Which is th ebest way to store the Facebook data. What steps should I take to avoid storing duplicate posts and how can we retrive those data based on conditions.

For example if we try to retrieve posts about football, facebook returns as json object and we can store in mongodb. If we try to fetch posts about football after an hour, we should not be inserting duplicare posts posted by same user id and same time. Similarly if I want to retrieve records related to football, I should be able to fetch only those records and not records related to tennis assuming records exist for tennis.

Kindly clarify or post your opinion and suggestions. it would be of great help.

Thanks,
Balaji D

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to store you data in mongodb depends on the behaviour of your application; e.g. if it's going to be write-heavy, or read-only, etc.  I recommend reading about [mongodb schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design).  In terms of dealing with Facebook data specifically, you might want to check out this similar post from a user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637061/facebook-user-id-as-mongodb-bson-objectid)